# Length of Trend - Panel Data

Tags: r, time-series, data.table, zoo

I have a well balanced panel data set which contains NA observations. I will be using LOCF, and would like to know how many consecutive NA's are in each panel, before carrying observations forward. LOCF is a procedure where by missing values can be "filled in" using the "last observation carried forward". This can make sense it some time-series applications; perhaps we have weather data in 5 minute increments: a good guess at the value of a missing observation might be an observation made 5 minutes earlier.

Obviously, it makes more sense to carry an observation forward one hour within one panel than it does to carry that same observation forward to the next year in the same panel.

I am aware that you can set a "maxgap" argument using zoo::na.locf, however, I want to get a better feel for my data. Please see a simple example:

```
require(data.table)
set.seed(12345)

### Create a "panel" data set
data <- data.table(id = rep(1:10, each = 10),
                   date = seq(as.POSIXct('2012-01-01'),
                              as.POSIXct('2012-01-10'),
                              by = '1 day'),
                   x  = runif(100))

### Randomly assign NA's to our "x" variable
na <- sample(1:100, size = 52)
data[na, x := NA]

### Calculate the max number of consecutive NA's by group...this is what I want:
### ID       Consecutive NA's
  #  1       1
  #  2       3
  #  3       3
  #  4       3
  #  5       4
  #  6       5
  #  ...
  #  10      2

### Count the total number of NA's by group...this is as far as I get:
data[is.na(x), .N, by = id]
```

All solutions are welcomed, but data.table solutions are highly preferred; the data file is large.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will do it:

```
data[, max(with(rle(is.na(x)), lengths[values])), by = id]
```

I just ran `rle` to find all consecutive `NA`'s and picked the max length.

---

Here's a rather convoluted answer to the comment question of recovering the date ranges for the above `max`:

```
data[, {
         tmp = rle(is.na(x));
         tmp$lengths[!tmp$values] = 0;  # modify rle result to ignore non-NA's
         n = which.max(tmp$lengths);    # find the index in rle of longest NA sequence

         tmp = rle(is.na(x));                   # let's get back to the unmodified rle
         start = sum(tmp$lengths[0:(n-1)]) + 1; # and find the start and end indices
         end   = sum(tmp$lengths[1:n]);

         list(date[start], date[end], max(tmp$lengths[tmp$values]))
       }, by = id]
```

Comment: +1 This is much better since the other lengths are unimportant.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you! Now, if I want to go back to my data and see when these longs series of missing values occur, is there an easy way to attach date ranges the data.table your code spits out?

Comment: @Andreas Careful use of `cumsum` on the `lengths` component of `rle(is.na(x))` can recover the starting position of each series.

Comment: Excellent idea. I can see how "cumsum"lets us map out the length of a run to a particular value. The next trick will be sorting this out across ID's. Some new things to think about...Thank you!

Comment: @Andreas - see edit - that solution can be optimized a bit if needed, but it should give you the basic tools to go forward

Comment: Wow, Eddi, this is really great. Thank you! Out of curiosity, how do you compose such lengthy data.table statements? For example, when I think about how to construct a function which will then be applied to every element of a vector, I start by constructing the function to perform a data step on just one element. Then, once it works, I wrap it inside an "apply" function and I'm done. With data.table, I'm having a hard time prototyping functions. The problem is not made easier by the fact that data.table is used for big data, so visualizing the data seems to always pose a problem...

Comment: @Andreas I simply created a tiny toy vector in my main environment and caressed it into spitting out `start` and `end` as above. Once that was done, transitioning to `data.table` is trivial - you just put it into your `j` expression and at the end return whatever you like (dates and number in this case). And the really great thing about `data.table` is that I don't even spend an ounce of energy thinking about the `by` part, so that I only think about small problems at a time, and then `data.table` takes care of the rest.

Comment: @Eddi, this makes sense. It seems the approach is in fact similar to taking a "toy" example when creating functions. I will try this out with more patience next time, thank you! I also liked your trick to converting NA values to TRUE to coerce "rle" to working with NA's.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `rle` with the modification suggested [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-June/281736.html) (and pasted below) to count `NA` values.

```
foo  <- data[, rle(x), by=id]
foo[is.na(values), max(lengths), by=id]

#     id V1
# 1:  1  1
# 2:  2  3
# 3:  3  3
# 4:  4  3
# 5:  5  4
# 6:  6  5
# 7:  7  3
# 8:  8  5
# 9:  9  2
# 10: 10  2
```

Amended `rle` function:

```
rle<-function (x)
{
     if (!is.vector(x)&&  !is.list(x))
         stop("'x' must be an atomic vector")
     n<- length(x)
     if (n == 0L)
         return(structure(list(lengths = integer(), values = x),
             class = "rle"))

     #### BEGIN NEW SECTION PART 1 ####
     naRepFlag<-F
     if(any(is.na(x))){
         naRepFlag<-T
         IS_LOGIC<-ifelse(typeof(x)=="logical",T,F)

         if(typeof(x)=="logical"){
             x<-as.integer(x)
             naMaskVal<-2
         }else if(typeof(x)=="character"){
             naMaskVal<-paste(sample(c(letters,LETTERS,0:9),32,replace=T),collapse="")
         }else{
             naMaskVal<-max(0,abs(x[!is.infinite(x)]),na.rm=T)+1
         }

         x[which(is.na(x))]<-naMaskVal
     }
     #### END NEW SECTION PART 1 ####

     y<- x[-1L] != x[-n]
     i<- c(which(y), n)

     #### BEGIN NEW SECTION PART 2 ####
     if(naRepFlag)
         x[which(x==naMaskVal)]<-NA

     if(IS_LOGIC)
         x<-as.logical(x)
     #### END NEW SECTION PART 2 ####

     structure(list(lengths = diff(c(0L, i)), values = x[i]),
         class = "rle")
}
```