# Consecutive NAs in a column

Tags: r, list, na

I'd like to remove the rows that got more than 3 consecutive `NA`s in one column.

```
      [,1] [,2] 
[1,]    1    1   
[2,]   NA    1   
[3,]    2    4   
[4,]   NA    3   
[6,]    1    4   
[7,]   NA    8
[8,]   NA    5
[9,]   NA    6
```

so I'd have this data

```
      [,1] [,2] 
[1,]    1    1   
[2,]   NA    1   
[3,]    2    4   
[4,]   NA    3   
[6,]    1    4
```

I did a research and I tried this code

```
data[! rowSums(is.na(data)) >3  , ]
```

but I think this is only used for consecutive `NA`s in a row.

Comment: Search above for `[r] rle` as there are many answers already for the powerful `rle()` function which will help you here too.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16820072/length-of-trend-panel-data/16820379#16820379) should help and has a potentially misleading title.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As mentioned, `rle` is a good place to start:

```
is.na.rle <- rle(is.na(data[, 1]))
```

Since NAs are "bad" only when they come by three or more, we can re-write the values:

```
is.na.rle$values <- is.na.rle$values & is.na.rle$lengths >= 3
```

Finally, use `inverse.rle` to build the vector of indices to filter:

```
data[!inverse.rle(is.na.rle), ]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `rle`, or you could do this:

```
library(data.table)

d = data.table(a = c(1,NA,2,NA,3,4,NA,NA,NA), b = c(1:9))

d[d[, if(.N > 3) {.I[1]} else {.I}, by = cumsum(!is.na(a))]$V1]
#    a b
#1:  1 1
#2: NA 2
#3:  2 3
#4: NA 4
#5:  3 5
#6:  4 6
```

Run `d[, cumsum(!is.na(a))]` to see why this works. Also, I could've used `.SD` instead of `.I` to get cleaner code, but opted for efficiency instead.

Answer (score 2):

As @DirkEddelbuettel suggested, the `rle()` function will help.  You can create your own function to identify the elements of a vector with 3 or more consecutive NA values.

```
consecna <- function(x, n=3) {
    # function to identify elements with n or more consecutive NA values
    y <- rle(is.na(x))
    y$values <- y$lengths > (n - 0.5) & y$values
    inverse.rle(y)
    }
```

Then you can apply this function to each column of your matrix.

```
# example matrix of data
m <- matrix(c(1, NA, 2, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 4, 3, 4, 8, 5, 6), ncol=2)

# index matrix identifying elements with 3 or more consecutive NA values
mindex <- apply(m, 2, consecna)
```

Then use the created index matrix to get rid of all those rows that were identified.

```
# removal of all the identified rows
m2 <- m[!apply(mindex, 1, any), ]
```