# count the length of Number Sequences

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

Sample data containing some arithmetic sequences  c(4,5,6) and c(10,11).

```
 df <- data.frame(x = c(2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 11))
```

What I want it is a new column that count the length of the each sequence, such as

```
> df
   x cnt
1  2   1
2  4   1
3  5   2
4  6   3
5  8   1
6 10   1
7 11   2
```

It would be simple to first assign `df$cnt[1] = 1`, then for the second row and beyond just increment the count, or reset to `1` depending on if the consecutive numbers in df$x meet certain criteria (here `x[i] - x[i-1] == 1`).  I am just not sure loop is the way to go in `R`-- also I need to deal with groups.

I can create new column to check if it is in a sequence.  From there, I probably can use [`rle`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16820072/length-of-trend-panel-data) to calculate the run length and generate the `cnt` column (not sure how to do it with the `NA`).

```
> df %>% mutate(check=(x-lag(x)==1))
   x check
1  2    NA
2  4 FALSE
3  5  TRUE
4  6  TRUE
5  8 FALSE
6 10 FALSE
7 11  TRUE
```

Is this the way to go?  Please suggest solutions with `dplyr` or `data.table`?

Comment: Closely related - [rle-like function that catches runs of adjacent integers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8466807/903061)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**dplyr.** Set the `default` value and it will work:

```
df %>% mutate(check = x - lag(x, default = x[1L]) != 1) %>%
  group_by(g = cumsum(check)) %>% 
  mutate(cnt = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup %>% select(-g,-check)

      x   cnt
  <dbl> <int>
1     2     1
2     4     1
3     5     2
4     6     3
5     8     1
6    10     1
7    11     2
```

---

**data.table.** Along the same lines and more concisely:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, cnt := 1:.N, by=cumsum(x != shift(x, fill=x[1L]) + 1L)]

    x cnt
1:  2   1
2:  4   1
3:  5   2
4:  6   3
5:  8   1
6: 10   1
7: 11   2
```

`shift` is data.table's analogue to `lag`.

Alternately, from v1.9.7 of the package on, you're able to use `rowid` instead:

```
df[, cnt := rowid(cumsum(x != shift(x, fill=x[1L]) + 1L))]
```

Comment: I am getting `Error: expecting a single value` for **dplyr** solution. I think I am missing something.

Comment: @user It works for me on the example given (dplyr 0.5, r 3.2.4). I don't know why that error would happen, since it's usually triggered by `summarise`, which does not appear here.

Comment: I have `dplyr ‘0.4.3’ & R 3.2.5`. Maybe I am getting this error due to the version.

Comment: `data.table` solutions looks really nice.  It looks that you use `cumsum` to implement the function of `rle` ?  Is it faster?

Comment: @Dong I guess `cumsum` and `rle` cannot be substituted here. For example, if `x=c(1,2,3,5,7)` the correct indices should be `c(1,2,3,1,1)`, but if you use something like `rleid(x != shift(x, fill=x[1L]-1L) + 1L)`, you'll get `c(1,2,3,1,2)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Another option using `base R`

```
unlist(sapply(rle(cumsum(ifelse(diff(c(df$x[1],df$x))!=1,1,0)))$lengths,seq_len))
```